# simple example for the creation of a custom directory namer

Tags: symfony, file-upload, vichuploaderbundle

I have read the main idea of how Create a custom directory namer on [github](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/directory_namer/howto/create_a_custom_directory_namer.md). But, I did not manage to know how to start. So, I am wondering if there is simple example for it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a sample DirectoryNamer here:https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/242#issuecomment-44566041